# "the world over" vs "all over the world"

Tags: phrase-choice

I have seen many writers use "the world over" to mean something is happening all over the world.

Is not it more appropriate to use "all over the world" instead? "the world over" sounds like a twisted grammar to my ear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both correct. "The world over" is a common idiom. See: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+world+over